# neural network classifier - Validation loss increasing instead of decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a single‐layer neural network to classify activities based on each value of the body acceleration data for the 3 coordinates. I have processed the data by converting the labels to one‐hot encoding and reshaping the last 2 dimensions of the training data tensor so that instead of the shape being (n,128,3) it is (n,384) where n is the number of samples. The following code will do this I run the network, the loss increases rather than decreasing which I believe means its predictions are getting worse.

```
# Cast xtrain to float64 before reshaping
xtrain = np.reshape(xtrain, (-1, 128*3)).astype(np.float64)

# Split the data into train and validation sets
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(xtrain, ytrain, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Convert x_train and x_val to float64
x_train = tf.cast(x_train, tf.float64)
x_val = tf.cast(x_val, tf.float64)

# One-hot encode the target labels
y_train_encoded = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, dtype=np.float64)
y_val_encoded = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, dtype=np.float64)

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128*3, 6] ,dtype=tf.float64 ))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([6], dtype= tf.float64))

# predicted probability for each class
def y_pred(x):
    return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# cross entropy loss function
def loss(x, y):
    y_ = y_pred(x)
    return tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.math.log(y_), axis=[1]))
```

REPORTING ACCURACY

```
def accuracy(x,y):
   y_ = y_pred(x)
   # calculate where the prediction equals the label
   correct = tf.math.equal(tf.math.argmax(y_,axis=-1),tf.math.argmax(y,axis=-1))
   # convert to a float (previously boolean)
   correct = tf.cast(correct,dtype=tf.float64)
   # return the mean to give the overall accuracy
   return tf.math.reduce_mean(correct)

# Create a directory for TensorBoard logs
log_dir = './logs'
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)

train_steps = 3000
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

train_loss_list = []
val_loss_list = []

print('--- Training with', train_steps, 'steps ---')
for i in range(train_steps):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        current_loss = loss(x_train, y_train_encoded)
    gradients = tape.gradient(current_loss, [W, b])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [W, b]))
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('Training Step:', i, 'Loss =', current_loss.numpy())
    train_loss_list.append(current_loss.numpy())

    # Calculate validation loss
    val_loss = loss(x_val, y_val_encoded)
    val_loss_list.append(val_loss.numpy())

    # Log the training and validation loss
    with summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('Training Loss', current_loss.numpy(), step=i)
        tf.summary.scalar('Validation Loss', val_loss.numpy(), step=i)

train_accuracy = accuracy(x_train, y_train_encoded)
val_accuracy = accuracy(x_val, y_val_encoded)

print('Training accuracy:', train_accuracy.numpy())
print('Validation accuracy:', val_accuracy.numpy())

print('Final Training Loss:', train_loss_list[-1])
print('Final Validation Loss:', val_loss_list[-1])

# Close the summary writer after training
summary_writer.close()


%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir logs
```

While my training loss is decreasing with the training steps.

[image]

My validation loss is increasing so i bealive I am doing something wrong. Could anybody tell me where i am going wrong?

I am fairly new at using python and Tensorflow so thanks for the patience in advance.

[image]